# javascript output not showing in html

Tags: javascript, html, string

I’m trying to write code that removes some special characters from any string URL and then displays the cleaned string via html.

The JavaScript works but I can’t get the result to show in the browser.

The whole point of the code is to have someone put in input and then the input is then cleaned up and the result is then inserted in “result1” and/or “result2”

So when the page loads and the user types something in “myTextarea” and clicks the button, `cleanupurl(x)` is supposed to run.

pls help ;(

**code so far**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Clean Strings</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div id="display-area" >  
                <textarea placeholder="insert URL here :)" id="myTextarea">.      
                </textarea>
                <button class = 'btn btn-default' id="demo" onclick=“cleanupurl(myTextarea.text())> Cleanup URL</button>
            </div>

            <div id ="result1">
                <p></p>
            </div>

            <div id ="result2">
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
   <script>
    var splitstring = [''];
    var finaloutput = ''; var i = 0;

    function cleanupurl(urlstring) {


        //==========================================//
        urlstring = urlstring.replace(/%21/gi, '!'); 
        urlstring = urlstring.replace(/%23/gi, '#');
        urlstring = urlstring.replace(/%24/gi, '$');
        urlstring = urlstring.replace(/%26/gi, '&');

        //==========================================//
        splitstring = urlstring.split('http://');
        document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML =  cleanurloutput1();
        //return 
    }

    function cleanurloutput1(){
    return splitstring[1];
        }

    function cleanurloutput2(){
    return splitstring[2];
        }

        //document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = cleanurloutput1();

        var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
        cleanupurl(x);



    </script>
```

Comment: if none of the answers below have helped you then please edit your question with more specific information.

Answer (score 2):

Your `onclick` is passing `myTextarea.text()` while the element `myTextArea` doesn't have `text` method (check your browser's console for errors).

use `myTextarea.value` instead

```
<button class='btn btn-default' id="demo" onclick=“cleanupurl( myTextarea.value ) > Cleanup URL</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

so the first problem I encountered when I ran your code in my browser using the debug tool was:

- I found that you had included **illegal character** which was ths character ( **“** ) it looks like a double quote but I am sure it has a different ASCII value. I found it at this point 
  `“cleanupurl(myTextarea.text())`

I completely rewrote that line to appear like this:

```html
<button class = 'btn btn-default' id="demo" onclick="cleanupurl();"> Cleanup URL</button>
```

Then I made this change to your javascript.... And **Viola** Your code works

```
    function cleanupurl() {

    var urlstring = document.getElementById('myTextarea').value;
```